# Dynamically change input id with value - input type=range

Tags: javascript, forms, html, input, range

I'm making a phone gap query mobile iOS app for course evaluation at my uni. This app primary function will be a form that in it's original form uses radio buttons where each value also has a corresponding id - e.g.

```
<input name="q10" id="1" value="1" type="radio" />
<input name="q10" id="2" value="2" type="radio" />
<input name="q10" id="3" value="3" type="radio" />
<input name="q10" id="4" value="4" type="radio" />
<input name="q10" id="5" value="5" type="radio" />
<input name="q10" id="6" value="6" type="radio" />
```

But radio buttions aren't that intuitive on iOS devices so I'm using input type range instead.
This works great for changing the value between 1 and 6 but the problem is that one only specifies one id for the whole input, not one id per value.

```
<input type="range" name="q10" id="q10" value="0" min="0" max="6"  />
```

Is there a way to change the id with the value? I think this should be doable through JavaScript but I lack the know-how. I also cannot change the way the database is set up (requiring both id and value) as this database belongs to the university's IT-department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange) event

```
<input type="range" onchange="this.id=this.value" name="q10" id="q10" value="0" min="0" max="6" />
```

Working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/aVHm8/

**Note:** I always feel uneasy about changing the ID of a DOM element .. perhaps you should investigate better options to resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The database can't know what the `id` is unless you use JavaScript to send it to the server (standard form submission sends the `name` and the `value`). In which case find the bit of JS that pulls out the ID and just send the value twice instead.